# What are the xpaths from this XML file?

Tags: postgresql

```
<root>
 <level OPERATORE="maria bianca_amadeo" QUARTIERE="Quartiere 1 - Ricerca 
 oggetti - Versione a" LEVEL="1" DATA="2016-04-18 17:59">
  <track X="-237" Y="0" Z="155" TEMPO="0" />
  <track X="-237" Y="0" Z="155" TEMPO="2" />
  <track X="-238" Y="0" Z="155" TEMPO="4" />
  <track X="-249" Y="0" Z="161" TEMPO="6" />
  <track X="-260" Y="0" Z="167" TEMPO="8" />

CREATE TABLE public.james AS
SELECT (xpath('//root/level/track', x))[1]::text AS id
FROM   unnest(xpath('/root/level/track', myxml)) x;
RETURN TRUE;
```

How can I select the rows contains X,Y,Z and Tempo?
The result would give all the rows.

Comment: All the rows in your example contain X,Y,Z and TEMPO, or do you want specific values only?

Comment: i want all the rows